# How to run a command from terminal so that it will be executed without tty?

Tags: shell-script, cron

**The situation:** I have a bash script that is intended to run with cron. I tested the script on the terminal and it was running fine. As I configured the script to be executed by cron, the script started failing.

It took me a LOT of effort to find out that one of the commands in the script required TTY to run, which is not provided in the cron's execution environment. (For the curious: the command was `docker-compose` failing with the message `the input device is not a TTY`)

**The question:** I still would like to find a way to test my shell scripts from the terminal before configuring them for cron. Is there a way to run a shell script from a terminal so as if it is run by cron? Like `cron run_my_command_now 'echo 123'`. Or may be there is just a way to run a shell script from the terminal, so that the script thinks there is no terminal?

Comment: You do mean the binary `tty` right?

Comment: @mashuptwice the command `docker-compose` was failing with the message `the input device is not a TTY`.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty and this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5696

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest way is probably to use ssh with '-T' to disable the pseudo TTY.

```
ssh -T localhost "command"
```

Should run it with no TTY.

Comment: Nowhere does the question mention "ssh", hence it might not be applicable as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

See the at(1) man page.

`at -f /path/to/script_or_command now +5 min`

Or something similar to (EOT is Ctrl-D):

```
$ at 16:05
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> source /my/environment/file
at> /path/to/script 
at> <EOT>
job 1 at Mon Feb 14 16:05:00 2022
```